# Book Recommendation On Game Theory

Tags: book-recommendation, game-theory

I am currently doing a degree in Discrete Mathematics. I have background in Real Analysis, Probability theory, Graph Theory and Random graph. But I will be taking a course on **Game Theory** next semester, which is one field I am very much interested in.
Are there introductory books, video links and approaches you can recommend to help me master this course.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

The folks from Yale have an amazing, very accesible, easy to follow course in Game Theory. It is fairly introductory, which I think is what you're looking for, [here's is the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nM3rTU927io) to first lecture.

As for books, these are my recommendations

- [Game Theory: An Introduction (Steven Tadelis)](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691129082/game-theory): Comprehensive text book, if you're looking for problem sets to practice, this one will help you
- [Game Theory (E. N. Barron)](http://webpages.math.luc.edu/%7Eenb/gamebook.pdf): This one is shorter, and more mathematically formal
- [Theory of Games and Economic Behavior (John von Neumann & Oskar Morgenstern](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691130613/theory-of-games-and-economic-behavior): I wouldn't start with this one, but would definitely recommend it if you are enjoying the subject

Comment: Thanks @caverac. This is really nice.