# Book recommendation for game theory

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

Does anyone know of any good books that summarize the history, main results, and applications of game theory?  I'm not looking for a textbook for an introductory course (proofs can be omitted), but rather something a mathematically-inclined layman (say, with knowledge of calculus but no formal training in linear algebra) might read to get a feel for the subject.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4219577/book-recommendation-on-game-theory) answer your question?

Comment: Not particularly; as stated above, I'm *not* looking for a textbook, and the target audience has no background in analysis.

Comment: The DeVos-Kent book, albeit a "textbook," is readable and friendly, but still rigorous, and meets your prereq assumptions.

Comment: @Randall Just browsed through a few pages of it, and this does indeed look like it fits the bill.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Game theory textbooks/lectures/etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44246/game-theory-textbooks-lectures-etc)

Comment: I had already seen that thread before posting this one; out of it, the only rec that seems particularly appropriate is Playing for Real (which has been recommended separately below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Playing for Real](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/playing-for-real-9780195300574)* by Ken Binmore sounds like a perfect fit for what you are looking for. It is very readable with lots of examples, non-mathematical discussions and applications to other sciences.

Comment: That looks interesting. I'ma get myself a hard copy.